# Python Selenium using different proxy for each window not working

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I have some code that opens a Chrome window for each proxy using Selenium and python. I want even window to have its own proxy. I'm having trouble setting a custom proxy for the window and I get the error "ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES" when I try to load a webpage.

I looked at multiple tutorials and I'm setting the proxy in the correct way. My proxy is valid but may be formatted in the wrong way here's an example:

126.201.39.0:64356:username:password

```
from audioop import error
import pickle
import os
import base64
import string 
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import email
from apiclient import errors
from webbrowser import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from random import randint, random, uniform
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re
import smtplib
import multiprocessing


class UserCredentials:
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password


proxyList = ["134.202.29.0:61234:butterfly0:Q0ILdE2o", "134.202.29.1:61234:butterfly1:lD7B1K90", "134.202.29.2:61234:butterfly2:z0OM3dN1"]

users_array = [
    UserCredentials(email="user1@example.com", password="password1"),
    UserCredentials(email="user2@example.com", password="password2"),
    UserCredentials(email="user3@example.com", password="password3")
]

def get_driver(proxy):
    options = Options()

    prefs = {"credentials_enable_service": False,
        "profile.password_manager_enabled": False}

    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)

    # add to be auto logged in
    # userdatadir = 'C:/Users/zaida/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data' 
    # options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={userdatadir}")

    ser = Service("chromedriver.exe")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)

    return driver
    

def worker(proxy):
    driver = get_driver(proxy)
    goNike(driver)

def goNike(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.nike.com/")

    time.sleep(1000)

def main():
    processes = []
    for proxy in proxyList:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(proxy,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use different proxies for each Chrome window with Selenium in Python.

```bash
+-------------------+       +-------------------+
| Python Script     |       | Selenium WebDriver|
| - Creates multiple|  ---> | - Each instance   |
|   processes       |       |   has a proxy     |
+-------------------+       +-------------------+
```

Your proxies have the format `IP:PORT:USERNAME:PASSWORD`, which is not directly compatible with [Selenium's proxy setting methods](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/set-proxy-in-selenium). [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) expects the proxy to be in the format `IP:PORT`. The authentication (username and password) for the proxy needs to be handled differently.

So you would need to separate the proxy IP and port from the username and password. The username and password can be injected into the browser through a script or handled via a [proxy auto-config (PAC) file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Proxy_servers_and_tunneling/Proxy_Auto-Configuration_PAC_file).

For instance, you can modify your `get_driver` function:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

def get_driver(proxy):
    ip_port, username, password = proxy.split(':')[:2], proxy.split(':')[2], proxy.split(':')[3]

    options = Options()
    # [your existing options] 

    # Set up the proxy
    proxy = Proxy()
    proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
    proxy.http_proxy = ip_port
    proxy.ssl_proxy = ip_port
    options.Proxy = proxy
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server=http://{}".format(ip_port))

    ser = Service("chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)

    # Inject the username and password for proxy authentication
    script = '''
        var username = "{}";
        var password = "{}";
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://proxyauth.com", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
    '''.format(username, password)
    driver.execute_script(script)

    return driver
```

That requires the proxy server to support this kind of authentication. If your proxy server does not support it, you might need to use a different method, like a PAC file or a browser extension for proxy authentication.

Comment: Thanks can you look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77950696/constructing-grammar-based-on-given-rules

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower Sure, I have posted an answer there.

Comment: Thanks VonC not sure if you could help with Cryptography but here's one: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/109738/proving-set-of-functions-are-not-a-prf-family

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower That seems... way outside my area of expertise!

Comment: No problem maybe another swift question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78011542/resizing-video-sometimes-hides-video-controls-swift-ui