# Constructing grammar based on given rules

Tags: binary, grammar, context-free-grammar, parse-tree

I have to construct a certain grammar for a given language where the language consists of strings of 0s and 1s that are the binary repr. of odd numbers greater that 6. I also have to create a parse tree for something like 10001 which is 17. How do I go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a grammar for a language consisting of strings of 0s and 1s that represent binary representations of odd numbers greater than 6, you can:

- identify the patterns: Odd numbers in binary always end with a 1. Numbers greater than 6 (in binary, greater than 110) must have at least 4 digits because 111 (7 in binary) is the smallest 3-digit odd number greater than 6.
- Define a [context-free grammar (CFG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) for this language. That grammar needs to make sure that:

  - the number is at least 4 digits long.
  - it ends with a 1 (to make sure it is odd).
  - it starts with at least 1001 to guarantee it is greater than 6.

You can set:

- `S` as the start symbol.
- `B` as a non-terminal that generates any binary digit (0 or 1).
- `F` as a non-terminal that generates a string ending in 1.

With the grammar:

```
S → 1F | 10F | 11F
F → 001 | 01 | 1F | 0F | BBF
B → 0 | 1
```

It starts by making sure the binary representation begins with `1` (so it is an actual binary number and not just a string of 0s), and it allows for generation of numbers that are at least 4 digits long and end with a `1`.

```
S → 1F |   10F  | 11F
     |       |      |
     ↓       ↓      ↓
     F       F      F
    /|\     /|\    /|\
   001 01  1F 0F  BBF 1
```

---

### Parse Tree for 10001 (17 in binary)

It fits the pattern defined by this grammar: it is a binary number greater than 6 and odd.

```
        S
        |
       10F
        |
       001  (Since 10001 ends in 001 after the initial 10)
        |
       1 (Terminal, ending the string with an odd number)
```

---

Actually, checking the Wikipedia definition of [context-free grammar (CFG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar):

A context-free grammar `G` is a 4-tuple `G = (V, Σ, R, S)` where:

1. `V` is a finite set; each element `v ∈ V` is called a variable. Each variable represents a different type of phrase
   or clause in the sentence.
2. `Σ` is a finite set of terminals, disjoint from `V`, which make up the actual content of the sentence. The set of
   terminals is the alphabet of the language defined by the grammar `G`.
3. `R` is a finite relation in `(V × (V ∪ Σ)*)`. The members of `R` are called productions of the grammar (symbolized
   by `P`).
4. `S` is the start variable, used to represent the whole sentence. It must be an element of `V`.

In your case:

- **Variables (V)**: `S` (start), `B` (binary digits), `E` (end with 1)
- **Terminals (Σ)**: `0`, `1`
- **Productions (R)**:

  - `S → 1B1` (starts and ends with 1, ensuring it is odd and greater than a certain minimum)
  - `B → 0B | 1B | ε` (generates binary sequences)
  - `E → 1` (ensures the string ends with 1, making it odd)
- **Start Variable (S)**: `S`

That way, I can use [`0x51-dev/cfg`](https://github.com/0x51-dev/cfg) in [Go](https://go.dev).
You can execute this example in the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/0FZ27_m9BZt)

It returns:

> ```
> 10001 is a valid representation of an odd number greater than 6.
> ```

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/0x51-dev/cfg"
)

func main() {
    S := cfg.Variable("S")
    B := cfg.Variable("B")
    zero := cfg.Terminal("0")
    one := cfg.Terminal("1")

    g, err := cfg.New(
        []cfg.Variable{S, B}, // Variables
        []cfg.Terminal{zero, one}, // Terminals
        []cfg.Production{ // Productions
            cfg.NewProduction(S, []cfg.Beta{one, B, one}),
            cfg.NewProduction(B, []cfg.Beta{zero, B}),
            cfg.NewProduction(B, []cfg.Beta{one, B}),
            cfg.NewProduction(B, []cfg.Beta{cfg.Epsilon}),
        },
        S, // Start Variable
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating CFG:", err)
        return
    }

    binaryString := "10001" // Binary representation of 17
    _, ok := g.Evaluate(binaryString)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println(binaryString, "is a valid representation of an odd number greater than 6.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(binaryString, "is NOT a valid representation of an odd number greater than 6.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to clutch up and solve it my self.

[image]