# Resizing video sometimes hides video controls SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, video

I have a basic video player that is embedded inside of a scroll view. Because the video is inside a scroll view, its original aspect ratio is not maintained and therefore I have to get its aspect ratio and manually apply it. For some videos, applying the aspect ratio causes video controls (mute, full screen) to not be hidden. This has happened for videos with narrower aspect ratios so I'm assuming those controls just get cut out. What's a fix for this so (mute, full screen) always show?

[image: photo2]
[image: photo1]

```swift
struct HustleVideoPlayerR: View {
    let url: URL
    @State var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
    @State var value: Float = 0
    @State var viewID = false
    @State var aspect: CGSize = CGSize(width: 16, height: 9)
    @State private var currentTime: Double = 0.0
    @State private var totalLength: Double = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VideoPlayer(player: $player, showControls: true)
            .id(viewID)
            .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fit)
            .background(Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
            .onAppear {
                player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                viewID.toggle()
                
                Task {
                    do {
                        if let final = try await getVideoResolution(url: url.absoluteString) {
                            self.aspect = final
                        }
                    } catch { }
                }
                
                self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTime(seconds: 1.0, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: .main) { (_) in
                    self.value = self.getSliderValue()
                    
                    if self.value == 1.0 {
                        self.player.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1))
                        self.player.play()
                    }
                    if let total = self.player.currentItem?.duration.seconds, totalLength == 1.0 && total > 0.0 {
                        totalLength = total
                    }
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                self.player.pause()
                player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
                viewID.toggle()
            }
    }
    func getSliderValue() -> Float {
        if let total = self.player.currentItem?.duration.seconds, self.player.currentTime().seconds > 0.0, total > 0.0 {
            currentTime = self.player.currentTime().seconds
            return Float(currentTime / total)
        } else {
            return 0.0
        }
    }
}

struct VideoPlayer : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var player : AVPlayer
    let showControls: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) -> AVPlayerViewController {

        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        controller.showsPlaybackControls = showControls
        controller.allowsVideoFrameAnalysis = false
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: AVPlayerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoPlayer>) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution to try would be to make sure the [`VideoPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/videoplayer) always has enough space to display its controls, regardless of the aspect ratio of the video content.
That might involve making sure that the `ScrollView` allows for sufficient vertical space.

```swift
struct HustleVideoPlayerR: View {
    // your existing properties

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                VideoPlayer(player: $player, showControls: true)
                    .id(viewID)
                    .aspectRatio(aspect, contentMode: .fit)
                    .background(Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
                    // Add the rest of your .onAppear and other modifiers here
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / aspect.width * aspect.height)
        }
        .onAppear {
            // your existing onAppear code
        }
        // any other modifiers and functions
    }
}
```

By wrapping the `VideoPlayer` with a [`VStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack) and [`Spacer()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spacer/)s, you would make sure it is centered and constrained within a frame that respects the aspect ratio, but also allows the [`ScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview/) to scroll if needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this out. I'd appreciate help with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78014365/audio-player-does-not-play-url-audio-osstatus-error-2003334207