# Audio Player does not play url audio (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, audio

I have a video player that works when I capture audio recordings locally and store them in a location on the device. When I try to upload the audio recording to firestore the audio is correctly uploaded and I can paste the link into google to listen to the correct audio file. However when I try to use the same audio player to play the audio with firestore's link then I get the error below. I tried adding ".m4a" extension to the URL and removing it but I keep getting the same error.

Playback failed.The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Working URL's

**https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/audio%2F60787BCB-DEFE-4743-BF05-A2EAF24C0F28.m4a?alt=media&token=a29c8a9a-ce16-4240-9af1-5aefcac8a824.m4a**

**https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/audio%2F60787BCB-DEFE-4743-BF05-A2EAF24C0F28.m4a?alt=media&token=a29c8a9a-ce16-4240-9af1-5aefcac8a824**

audio player

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

public final class AudioPlayer: NSObject, ObservableObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    @Published public var soundSamples: [SampleModel] = []
    @Published public var isPlaying = false
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var currentSample: Float = 0
    private let numberOfSamples: Int
    private var durationTimer: Timer?
    var fileDuration: TimeInterval = 0
    var currentTime: Int = 0
    static let shared = AudioPlayer(numberOfSamples: 15)
        
    public init(isPlaying: Bool = false, audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(), timer: Timer? = nil, numberOfSamples: Int) {
        self.isPlaying = isPlaying
        self.audioPlayer = audioPlayer
        self.timer = timer
        self.numberOfSamples = numberOfSamples
    }
    
    func playSystemSound(soundID: SystemSoundID) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID)
    }
    
    func startPlayback(audio: URL) {
        let original = audio.absoluteString
        print(original)
        let updatedURL = original + ".m4a"
        print(updatedURL)
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .duckOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: updatedURL)!)
            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            audioPlayer.play()
            
            withAnimation {
                isPlaying = true
            }
            
            fileDuration = audioPlayer.duration.rounded()
            
            startMonitoring()
                        
        } catch let error {
            print("Playback failed.\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func startMonitoring() {
        audioPlayer.isMeteringEnabled = true
        currentTime = Int(fileDuration)
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.03, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.audioPlayer.updateMeters()
            this.currentSample = this.audioPlayer.peakPower(forChannel: 0)
            this.soundSamples.append(SampleModel(sample: this.currentSample))
        }
        
        durationTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { [weak self] _ in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            this.currentTime -= 1
        }
    }
    
    private func stopMonitoring() {
        soundSamples = []
        audioPlayer.isMeteringEnabled = false
        timer?.invalidate()
        durationTimer?.invalidate()
        currentTime = Int(fileDuration)
    }
    
    public func stopPlayback() {
        audioPlayer.stop()
        stopMonitoring()
        
        withAnimation {
            isPlaying = false
        }
    }
    
    public func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        if flag {
            stopPlayback()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At what line are you using the startPlayback function?

Comment: Did you check if the audio file exists or not? I think your issue is the audio path was changed.

Comment: A possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088594/osstatus-error-2003334207-when-using-avaudioplayer

Comment: @ElTomato the startPlayBack happens at the onAppear on the view. I didn't include it because that part isn't important to this. This isn't a duplicate, the problem in that thread is completely different.

Comment: @son Yes the audio file does exist and I said "audio is correctly uploaded and I can paste the link into google to listen to the correct audio file" in my question. I also added 2 urls in my question. Maybe this will help reproduce the issue as you can try and get the audio player working with those urls. Note the urls are the same but one has an added ".m4a" at the end, however they both work when searching them on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OSStatus error 2003334207` you are encountering when trying to play audio from a URL typically indicates an issue with the format of the URL or the media file itself, in this case, likely related to how you are handling the URL. From the description, it seems like the issue arises when trying to play audio files stored in [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) using their download URL in an `AVAudioPlayer`.

In your `startPlayback(audio: URL)` function, you are appending ".m4a" to the original URL, which could invalidate the URL if the ".m4a" extension is already present or not needed. Firestore URLs include access tokens and query parameters that are essential for accessing the content; altering the URL string can break these parameters.

See examples in "[Firebase / Upload files with Cloud Storage on Apple platforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files)", which illustrates that, once you've uploaded a file to Cloud Storage and obtained the download URL via the `downloadURL` method, this URL should be used as is to access the file.

Your `startPlayback(audio: URL)` function (without appending ".m4a") would be:

```swift
func startPlayback(audio: URL) {
    print(audio.absoluteString) // Verify the URL is correct
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .duckOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        
        // Use the URL directly without appending ".m4a"
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audio)
        audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
        audioPlayer.delegate = self
        audioPlayer.play()
        
        withAnimation {
            isPlaying = true
        }
        
        fileDuration = audioPlayer.duration.rounded()
        
        startMonitoring()
                        
    } catch let error {
        print("Playback failed.\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Make sure your [Firestore rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) allow for public access to the files or that your app properly authenticates to access private files.
Also, confirm the URLs are publicly accessible by testing them in a web browser or using a tool like `curl` to fetch the headers or content.

> I have already tried using the original URL without appending m4a, and it did not work. The audio file can be accessed publicly and there are no rules preventing access.

Then you have other potential causes for the `OSStatus error 2003334207`.

Even though you have confirmed the URL works in a browser, `AVAudioPlayer` might still have trouble with certain URL formats or parameters. Make sure the URL is properly encoded, especially if it contains special characters or spaces.

And make sure the MIME type of the hosted audio file is set correctly in Firestore. Though you mentioned the file is accessible, a mismatch in expected and actual MIME type could potentially cause playback issues.

As a diagnostic step, download the audio file programmatically and save it to the app's local storage. Attempt to play it from there using `AVAudioPlayer`. That can help isolate whether the issue is with the file itself or the streaming from a URL.

[`AVAudioPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayer/1387281-init) is generally designed for playing local files. For streaming audio from a URL, consider using [`AVPlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/) instead of `AVAudioPlayer`. `AVPlayer` is more suited to streaming media content over the network.

```swift
import AVFoundation
import SwiftUI

func startPlayback(audio: URL) {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, options: .duckOthers)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        
        // Use AVPlayer for network resources
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audio)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.play()
        
        withAnimation {
            isPlaying = true
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Playback failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

---

> Downloading the audio first, then playing it with `AVAudioPlayer` works.
>
> The only problem with using `AVPlayer` is that the function `startMonitoring` stops working because `AVPlayer` doesn't have metering.

Since downloading the audio first and then playing it locally with `AVAudioPlayer` (which supports metering) works, you could implement a workflow where the audio is temporarily downloaded to the device's storage before playback starts. That approach allows you to use `AVAudioPlayer` and retain the metering functionality. However, this may not be the most efficient method, especially for larger files or in scenarios where immediate playback is desired.

Or:

For streaming audio directly without downloading, you would need to use `AVPlayer` but implement a custom metering solution. Since `AVPlayer` does not provide native audio metering, you can use [`AVAudioEngine`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioengine) to tap into the audio playback signal and perform your own analysis.

- Create an `AVPlayer` instance for streaming your audio URL.
- Use `AVAudioEngine` to create an audio tap on the `AVPlayer's` output.
- Analyze the Audio Buffer: In the audio tap, analyze the audio buffer to calculate the level or power of the audio signal.

Here is a simplified example of setting up an audio tap on an `AVPlayerItem` to perform audio level metering. Note that this example focuses on the setup and does not include a full implementation of audio level calculation.

```swift
import AVFoundation

// Assume player is your AVPlayer instance
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioURL)
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let audioNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
let audioFormat = audioNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

// Attach and connect nodes
audioEngine.attach(audioNode)
audioEngine.connect(audioNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFormat)

// Install a tap on the node to capture audio data
audioNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: audioFormat) { (buffer, time) in
    // Analyze the buffer to get the audio level
    // Implementation of audio analysis goes here
}

do {
    try audioEngine.start()
} catch {
    print("Error starting audio engine: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

// Play the item with AVPlayer
player.play()

// Add audioNode to the audio signal chain
// Note: You will need to manage the timing and synchronization between AVPlayer playback and audioNode processing
```

Comment: Thanks I have already tried using the original url without appending m4a and it did not work. The audio file can be accessed publicly and there are no rules preventing access.

Comment: @JaxonSteinhower OK, I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. So you're right, downloading the audio first then playing it with AVAudioPlayer works. The only problem with using AVPlayer is that the function **startMonitoring** stops working because AVPlayer doesn't have metering. I read Apple's docs and it says "A URL that identifies the local audio file to play." so I think AVAudioPlayer only plays local audio. How can I get **startMonitoring** working with an AVPlayer?